# How to register a servlet in Spring Boot XML file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, registration

I wrote a servlet for a Spring Boot application. It worked when I used

```
contextHandler.addServlet(MyClass.class, "/v1/route");
```

Now I'm trying to register the servlet in beans.xml file as a bean. This one

```
<bean id="myId" class="com.abc.MyClass"/>
```

doesn't contain route. MyClass extends HttpServlet and overrides doGet method.

How to register a servlet which is also a bean?

Comment: Much depends on what you already have/your limitations, but [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet) should give you an overview and usable examples..

Comment: (...on registering servlets), when you want the servlet also to be a bean (which seems not to be a common use case on the internet ...but i heard of [some issues autowiring servlets](https://www.sourceallies.com/2012/02/injecting-spring-beans-into-java-servlets/)), i would just (pragmatically) try it by registering/declaring both: the servlet in the registration of your choice...and the bean... in your spring xml (/the configuration of your choice)

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me. It's a mix of declaration in XML and a fully programmatic registration.

In beans.xml file I've specified a constructor parameter which passed ServletContextHandler, like this:

```
<bean id="myId" class="com.abc.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="servletContextHandler"/>
</bean>
```

In MyClass constructor I'm adding the servlet - together with route - to the servlet holder, thus registering it as servlet:

```
public MyClass(ServletContextHandler h) {
    h.addServlet(new ServletHolder(this), "/v1/route");
}
```

Surely this can interfere with other requirements, like the constructor may need other parameters, other initializations may be needed. But here I'm registering a bean in XML and registering servlet programmatically. May be the servlet registration can also be done without explicit Java code, I don't know how to do that.

xerx593, I've seen that page but those examples didn't look good enough for what I wanted. Thank you anyway.